# Prototype JS: Selecting an element by its value?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, selector

I have an input type radio with a unique value. Is it possible to select that radio button by its unique value (147178) using Prototype JS? Thats the radio button:

```
<input type="radio" class="radio validate-nothing product-custom-option" value="147178">
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used Prototype JS in a while but this *should* work:

```
$$('input[type="radio"][value="147178"]')
```